# Sending a custom header via Google Chrome Headless

Tags: google-chrome, http, web, google-chrome-headless, webautomation

I am using Google Chrome Headless and telling it to browse to one of my endpoints.

I would like to make Google Chrome send a custom header when making requests to my endpoint.

How do I tell `google chrome headless` to send custom headers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [puppeteer docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.1.1/docs/api.md#pagesetextrahttpheadersheaders), this should be possible using page.setExtraHTTPHeaders(headers)

Try something on the following lines:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'my-custom-header': 'header-value'});
    await page.goto('http://my.request.endpoint');
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue,can somebody help me out? I tried the puppeteer code but it doesn't work.